# Chef Client For Windows Logging Not Working

Tags: chef-infra, chef-windows

Running my recipe from the command line....

```
O:\chef\cookbooks\wincfg>chef-client -L C:\chef\rds_deployment.log -l info -z -o wincfg::rds_deployment
```

A file C:\chef\rds_deployment.log does get created...but it's not containing the readable format that is still getting printed to stdout (on the console).

How do I get logging working so that what chef is logging to the console actually goes to a file? Note - I know I could redirect stdout via >>, but I want information on things that happen after reboots to end up in my log file as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you see on the console isn't from the logging system, that's formatter output and it is enabled automatically when outputting to a TTY. You can turn it back on with `--force-formatter` but it isn't intended to go to a log file. What you see in the log is the actual logger output.